# From " ? " to anonymous reporter "->"

Tags: netlogo

Im self-studying from the book “agent-based modelling in economics” (Hamill & Gilbert). There is on page 17:

```
let purchases filter [ member? ? [stock] of stall] shopping-list
foreach purchases [set shopping-list remove ? shopping-list]

;buy everything on my shopping-list that is for sale at this stall
;delete the items bought from the shopping list
```

If i understand correctly “ ? ” from Netlogo 5.0 does not work anymore in netlogo 6.0 and anonymous-reporter “->” should be used instead.

How can i write this using the "->" procedure?

I have read and tried to apply the examples in https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures but ended in no success

Comment: There is guidance on this https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#tasks-replaced-by-anonymous-procedures . And instead of saying your effort "ended in no success", show us your effort, and tell us what error message or other unexpected behavior you got, so we can help you fix it.